# Calling thread on member function

Tags: c++, multithreading

Sorry for the long example, but the question is simple. I'm using basic Visitor Pattern, with a mediator to manage several concrete Visitor_pick : public DataVisitor objects. The conrete mediator, SimulatorMediator, fills a list with Visitor_pick objects, then wants to call std::thread on a DataVisitor member function. I have tried several variants, using mem_fun1_t<>, etc., with no luck. Can't compile. What is the correct syntax?

The call in question should be at line 205 - I'd like to attach threads to v->visit_SpreadData, a unary function, then populate threadVec. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#include <thread>

class PublishEvent;
class Subscriber
{
 public:
   virtual void update(const PublishEvent *e) = 0;
   ~Subscriber() = default;
};

class Publisher
{
 public:
   void attach(Subscriber*);
   void detach(Subscriber*);
   void notify(const PublishEvent*);

 protected:
   std::list<Subscriber*> subscribers_;

};
inline void Publisher::
notify(const PublishEvent *e)
{
   for (auto &s : subscribers_)
     s->update(e);
}

inline void Publisher::
attach(Subscriber *s)
{
   subscribers_.push_back(s);
}

inline void Publisher::
detach(Subscriber *s)
{
   // inefficient for large nubmer of susbscribers
   subscribers_.remove(s);
}

class Mediator;
class SpreadData;
class DataElement;
class DataVisitor : public Publisher, public Subscriber
{
 public:
   virtual ~DataVisitor() {}
   // visit method
   virtual void visit_SpreadData(SpreadData *SD) = 0;
   // from Publisher::
   void update(const PublishEvent *e) override;
   void setMediator(Mediator *m)
     {
    m_ = m;
     }
   float get_payload() const
     {
    return payload_;
     }
   void set_payload(float p)
     {
    payload_ = p;
     }

   virtual void gendata(DataElement*) = 0;

 protected:
   DataVisitor() {}

 private:
   Mediator *m_;
   float payload_;
};

class DataElement
{
 public:
   virtual ~DataElement() {};
   void Accept(DataVisitor&);
 protected:
   DataElement() {};
};

void DataElement::Accept(DataVisitor &d)
{
   d.gendata(this);
}
class SpreadData : public DataElement
{
 public:
   typedef std::vector<float> return_data_type;

   SpreadData() { initiate(); };
   SpreadData(std::string filename) { initiate();};

   void printdata() const
     {
    std::copy(data_.begin(),
              data_.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " : "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
     }
   return_data_type getdata() const
     {
    return data_;
     }

 private:
   void initiate()
     {
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
      data_.push_back(static_cast<float>(i));
     }

   return_data_type data_;

};

void DataVisitor::update(const PublishEvent *e)
{
   // implementation details
};

template<int N>
class Visitor_pick : public DataVisitor
{
 public:
   Visitor_pick()
     {set_payload(0.); }
   // from DataVisitor
   void visit_SpreadData(SpreadData*) override;
   // from DataVisitor
   void gendata(DataElement*);
};

template<int N>
void Visitor_pick<N>::visit_SpreadData(SpreadData *SD)
{
   SD->Accept(*this);
}

template<int N>
void Visitor_pick<N>::gendata(DataElement *d)
{
   // implementation details
   SpreadData *SD = dynamic_cast<SpreadData*>(d);
   SpreadData::return_data_type r = SD->getdata();
   set_payload(r[N]);
}

class Mediator
{
 public:
   virtual ~Mediator() = default;
   virtual void mediate(DataElement*) = 0;

 protected:
   Mediator() = default;
   virtual void CreateVisitors() = 0;

   std::list<DataVisitor*> visitors_;
};

class Mediator_1 : public Mediator
{
 public:
   Mediator_1()
     {
    CreateVisitors();
     }
   void mediate(DataElement*);
 private:
   void CreateVisitors();
};

void Mediator_1::CreateVisitors()
{
   visitors_.push_back(new Visitor_pick<37>());
   visitors_.push_back(new Visitor_pick<42>());
   visitors_.push_back(new Visitor_pick<47>());
   visitors_.push_back(new Visitor_pick<52>());
   visitors_.push_back(new Visitor_pick<57>());
}
void Mediator_1::mediate(DataElement *SD)
{
   typedef std::mem_fun1_t<void,DataVisitor,SpreadData*> Visitor_fn;
   std::cout << "Mediating hard..." << std::endl;
   std::vector<std::thread> threadVec;
   for(auto &v : visitors_)
     {
    // Use Visitor_fn to spawn thread on
    // unary function v->visit_SpreadData,
    // place at back of threadVec
     }

   for_each(threadVec.begin(), threadVec.end(),
        std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));
   for(auto &v : visitors_)
     std::cout << "Payload: " << v->get_payload() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

   SpreadData *SD = new SpreadData();
   Mediator_1 *M = new Mediator_1();
   M->mediate(SD);

   delete SD;
   delete M;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Read the compilers error message carefully 2. Comment stuff out to narrow the problem down

Comment: Helpers like `mem_fn` are deprecated in favor of `bind`

Comment: You really should break this down.  90% of the code you posted is not necessary to explain your question.

Comment: I would just use `auto param = dynamic_cast<SpreadData*>(SD); if(param)threadVec.emplace_back(&DataVisitor::visit_SpreadData,v,param);`. No real need for `mem_fun` or even `bind`. Though, letting the number of elements define the number of threads is questionable to say the least.

Comment: @dauphic: Checking the standard, `std::mem_fn()` is certainly not in chapter D (Compatibility Features) but in 20.10.10. It would be a bit odd if `std::mem_fn()` were deprecated given it was only added with the most recent revision of the C++ standard. It seems you confuse `std::mem_fn()` with `std::mem_fun()`, `std::mem_fun_ref()` which are, indeed, deprecated.

Comment: Solution of PeterT worked as stated. The loop is free of mem_fun, or and binding. I agree with comment about number of threads determined by number of visitors - I'll use some variant of thread::hardware_concurrency() instead.